# Is there any kind of subspace clustering package available in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

Is there any kind of subspace clustering packages available in scikit-learn.

Comment: An example? I think it's not that clear what you're looking for.

Comment: @fireant, an example will not make this question less off-topic here on SO.

Comment: ELKI contains a number of subspace and correlation clustering algorithms. But they may not work half as well as you'd assume when reading the papers... I have yet to see one that really works.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is still interested. Yes, there is one that uses scikit-learn: [Subspace-Clustering](https://github.com/ChongYou/subspace-clustering).
It is a toolbox for large scale subspace clustering.
The clustering algorithms are implemented as two classes ElasticNetSubspaceClustering and SparseSubspaceClusteringOMP that have a fit function to learn the clusters. They may be used in the same way as the KMeans, SpectralClustering and others that are in sklearn.cluster.