# Dimensional reduction through subspace clustering

Tags: python, dimension-reduction

I am trying to write a framework in Python to compare different Dimensional-Reduction-Algorithms and I'm looking for a tutorial or implementation which uses subspace clustering Algorithms such as TSC, SSC, SSC-OMP for this goal. There is some Code written in Matlab related to [this paper](https://www.nari.ee.ethz.ch/commth/pubs/p/dim_red_sc_ext), but they are for me a little complicated to understand. I was wondering, if there is any library or implementaion in python for these.

Comment: Related question about subspace algorithms in scikit-learn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483160/is-there-any-kind-of-subspace-clustering-package-available-in-scikit-learn

Comment: It looks like the pyclustering package (https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/issues/381) will have CLIQUE subspace clustering implemented soon.  They are also interested in SSC (https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/issues/461).

Comment: Here is SSC-MPS (from quick Googling...): https://github.com/mitscha/ssc_mps_py

Comment: This package also has some implementations: https://github.com/siolag161/subspace_clustering. Docs: https://stage-document.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clustering.html.  It looks like that library wraps the OpenSubspace project (based on Weka).